# Checking if a function complies with a signature specified by Callable[]

Tags: python, python-typing

A function in Python may receive as an argument a choice of functions with different signatures. The signatures are specified using typing.Callable. Is there a way to check the received function against the specification and decide which one of them was actually given as parameter?

Example:

```
Option1 = Callable[[int], str]
Option2 = Callable[[str], str]

def somefunc(f: Union[Option1, Option2]):
   # I want to check here if f is of type Option1 or Option2
```

Comment: Why? What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: If you need to check which it is specifically, you should probably have two separate functions.

Comment: It's a kind of a wrapper that is common to multiple types of functions. I want to allow a user to wrap its function without having to worry which specific type of wrapper to use

Comment: Python is a dynamically typed language, which means that you can't know what type each parameter should be before calling the function correctly.

Comment: It would be a **very** bad practice in general, but if you insist on this pattern and require annotations on decorated functions (e.g. if `f` was declared without annotations - your code will fail), then [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) and check manually whether first argument is annotated with `int` or `str`. Again, don't do it in production, it is appropriate only for toy code, because requiring annotations is never a good solution, and using them on runtime is much worse (you don't support `object`, `Any` or smth more complex)

Comment: [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) provides more information than `typing.get_type_hints` does. For example, `inspect.signature` preservers information about order of args and about which args are keyword-only.

Answer (score 1):

Out of left field, here is a very different approach using Abstract Base Classes. The callables `option1` and `option2` here are legitimate instances of `Option1` and `Option2`, respectively:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Union


class Option1(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, _: int) -> str:
        ...


class Option2(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, _: str) -> str:
        ...


class Option1Impl(Option1):
    def __call__(self, _: int) -> str:
        return "takes int"


class Option2Impl(Option2):
    def __call__(self, _: str) -> str:
        return "takes str"


option1 = Option1Impl()
option2 = Option2Impl()


def somefunc(f: Union[Option1, Option2]) -> str:
    if isinstance(f, Option1):
        return "Option1"
    elif isinstance(f, Option2):
        return "Option2"
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"Got f of unexpected type: {type(f)}")


assert somefunc(option1) == "Option1"
assert somefunc(option2) == "Option2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach hacked together using [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature).
Basically, `somefunc` inspects the signature of the passed callable, verifies that it takes exactly one argument, and checks the type annotation of that argument.

```py
import inspect
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Union

Option1 = Callable[[int], str]
Option2 = Callable[[str], str]


def option1(_: int) -> str:
    ...


def option2(_: str) -> str:
    ...


def somefunc(f: Union[Option1, Option2]) -> str:
    signature = inspect.signature(f)
    assert len(signature.parameters) == 1, "f should take exactly one argument"
    (parameter,) = signature.parameters.values()  # unpack the parameter
    annotation = parameter.annotation
    if annotation is int:
        return "integer"
    elif annotation is str:
        return "string"
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"The first arg of f has unexpected {annotation=}")


assert somefunc(option1) == "integer"
assert somefunc(option2) == "string"
```

The assertions in the above code pass (running with Python 3.10).

##### Comments

The approach here is quite manual. This process (of signature inspection and of comparison with each of several candidate callable signatures) could be automated by a library in the spirit of [beartype](https://github.com/beartype/beartype) or [typeguard](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard). Both of these libraries provide some "runtime type-safety" features, but neither of them (as of this writing) do deep validation of callable signatures.